# Custom activity dialog displays weird on Nexus5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

```
Android Studio 0.4.5
```

Hello,

Activity Dialog displays funny when running on Nexus5.
[image]

However, when running on an Nexus4 4.4.2 emulator. (I don't have a Nexus5 emulator). It displays correctly. I have tested it on a Acer Z130 hardware which displays correctly.

I have created a Dialog from an Activity.

```
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 19
```

My dialog xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRabbitLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#ff20a3ff"
        android:contentDescription="Logo of App" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUpdateDlgEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickCancel"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickUpdate"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickDelete"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity in the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/dialogStyle"
    android:name="com.ssd.busb.Dialog_update" >
</activity>
```

And my custom styles are:

```
<style name="dialogStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Displayed correct on emulator Nexus4:

Comment: Do you have a different layout for hi-res screens like the Nexus 5?

Comment: Actually, I have just restarted Android Studio. And tested again on the Nexus4 emulator, and have experienced the same problem on that. But not as bad. I am support SDK min 10, not sure if that has anything to do with support a min 10.

Comment: I have just installed on a GalaxyNexus emulator 720x1280. Seems to display ok. It seems it might be just the Nexus5.